# Eliminar un elemento de una lista de Haskell

Tags: funciones, haskell, programación-funcional

Necesito ayuda para hacer una función en haskell en la que se le de una lista y un numero y despues regrese la lista sin el numero dado

Ingrese [1,2,3,4,4,4,5] 4 
Muestre [1,2,3,5]

De esta manera
quitaElemento :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> [a]

Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Se puede hacer un filtro, por ejemplo asi:

```
quitarElemento::Eq a=>[a]->a->[a]
quitarElemento [] e = []
quitarElemento (x:xs) e 
    | x == e = quitarElemento xs e
    | otherwise = x:( quitarElemento xs e )
```

Esta es una manera de eliminar el elemento.

Answer (score 0):

La manera más fácil sería utilizando una lista por comprensión:

```
quitaElemento :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> [a]
quitaElemento l n = [ x | x <- l , x /= n]
```

Answer (score -1):

--- utilizando filter

```
elimine_todos2 :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
elimine_todos2 n l = filter(\x -> x/=n) l
```

Comment: Revisa [answer], para que tú respuesta con código sin ninguna explicación, sea bien aceptada y no se marque como de baja calidad por su extensión y contenido.